# Django BinaryField not rendering

Tags: django

I have a model in which I have a BinaryField. When I go in the admin area, and try to add new city using the model form, the checkbox for the BinaryField doesn't get rendered.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    enabled = models.BinaryField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["id"]
        verbose_name = 'city'
        verbose_name_plural = 'cities'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import City

# Register your models here.
class CityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name']

    class Meta:
        model = City

admin.site.register(City, CityAdmin)
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label class="required" for="id_name">Name:</label>
    <input class="vTextField" id="id_name" maxlength="100" name="name" type="text">
</div>
```

As you can see in HTML, the checkbox input element is not there at all. I have checked, the migrations looks just fine, the field exists in the database as well. My virtual environment is setup to use Django 1.7.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need BooleanField.  BinaryField is for binary data.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield